# Django - Channels 2.0: Unable to connect to consumer

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-channels

I'm doing some tests before migrating from Channels 1.x to 2.x; my original code ingests the values of csv files into the database. However I'm currently unable to establish a connection to the consumer.

settings.py

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = "UbiosData.routing.application"
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("localhost", 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

routing.py

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, ChannelNameRouter
from .consumers import TestConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "channel": ChannelNameRouter({
        "somename": TestConsumer,
    }),
})
```

consumers.py

```
from channels.consumer import SyncConsumer

class TestConsumer(SyncConsumer):

    def websocket_connect(self, event):
        print("websocket_connect")
        self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept",
        })

    def websocket_receive(self, event):
        print("websocket_receive")
        self.send({
            "type": "websocket.send",
            "text": event["text"],
        })

    def test_send(self, message):
        print("Entering consumer")
        print(message["text"])
```

views.py

```
def test_channels(request):
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    print(channel_layer)
    channel_layer.send("somename", {
        "type": "test.send",
        "text": "test"
    })
    return render(request, "data/data_index.html")
```

Result of print statement in the `test_channels` function:

```
RedisChannelLayer(hosts=[{'address': ('localhost', 6379)}])
```

The print statements in the consumer are not executed, and I get no error message.
I'm using Python 3.5.3, channels 2.0.2 and channels-redis 2.0.2

**EDIT:** Here's the output when I launch the development server with my old project, using Channels 1.1.6:

```
Starting Channels development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Channel layer default (asgi_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer)
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
2018-02-16 16:46:48,604 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, ingest_equipment, ingest_values, websocket.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
2018-02-16 16:46:48,606 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, ingest_equipment, ingest_values, websocket.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
2018-02-16 16:46:48,608 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, ingest_equipment, ingest_values, websocket.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
2018-02-16 16:46:48,609 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, ingest_equipment, ingest_values, websocket.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
2018-02-16 16:46:48,611 - INFO - server - HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2018-02-16 16:46:48,611 - INFO - server - Using busy-loop synchronous mode on channel layer
2018-02-16 16:46:48,611 - INFO - server - Listening on endpoint tcp:port=8000:interface=127.0.0.1
```

Here's the output when I launch the server with the new project using Channels 2.0.2:

```
Starting ASGI/Channels development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
2018-02-16 17:05:08,331 - INFO - server - HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2018-02-16 17:05:08,332 - INFO - server - Configuring endpoint tcp:port=8000:interface=127.0.0.1
2018-02-16 17:05:08,334 - INFO - server - Listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8000
```

You'll notice that "worker - Listening on channels" is missing when I use Channels 2...

Comment: How does your JS look?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid I have no Javascript implemented at the moment, I'm just trying to get the print statement to work.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I misread.

Comment: Have you tried it from the `django shell`?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid I'm sorry I'm not sure how to do that, could you please elaborate?

Comment: within your project run `python manage.py shell` and then import `get_channel_layer` and run it to see what it returns.

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid ImportError: No module named 'get_channel_layer'

Comment: You need to import it from `channels` the same as you do in your file

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid `C:\Users\Smoky05\PycharmProjects\UbiosData\data\views.py:21: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'RedisChannelLayer.send' was never awaited
  "text": "test"
<HttpResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Comment: You will need to dig in to your views there and see what's up. Something isn't being initialised properly I think

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid Thank you, I now have something to investigate.

Comment: Good luck with it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:
"Remember that channel layers only support async methods, so you can either call it from your own asynchronous context" or "you’ll need to use async_to_sync". Since the consumer you're sending to inherits from a syncronous class (SyncConsumer), I think the second option is what you want. So add

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
```

and then change

```
channel_layer.send("somename", {
    "type": "test.send",
    "text": "test"
})
```

to

```
async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)("somename", {
    "type": "test.send",
    "text": "test"
})
```

**EDIT:**

Yep, you're spot-on:

> You'll notice that "worker - Listening on channels" is missing when I use Channels 2...

Since you're using ChannelNameRouter, you'll have to run a worker to handle events on your custom-named channel. You can do it like this:

```
./manage.py runworker somename
```

and if you later add more named channels, it's just as easy:

```
./manage.py runworker somename othername yetanothername
```

And don't forget to do the async_to_sync business as described above, it is still needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it didn't work, I get the same result; however, it made me take a second look at my problem and I discovered something, I edited my question.

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for the edit. I updated my answer, and it should get you on your way. Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: And you're spot-on on your answer ;-)  I had seen that in the [docs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/worker.html) and tried it but I don't think I had launched `python manage.py runserver` at the same time... for some reason ;-)  Result of current code: `Entering consumer` and `test`.  The concept of sync/async is still unclear to me though, I'll need to look into that.  Anyway thank you very much!